# Why does calling ensureCapacity(Integer.MAX_VALUE) throws OOME?

Tags: collections

Here is a situation below:-

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

listOfLists.ensureCapacity(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Below is the stack trace:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3210)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:261)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:235)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(ArrayList.java:218)
    at com.ankit.collections.OOMETest.main(OOMETest.java:10)
```

Why does jvm throw OOME here? My Heap memory is about 2 GB ~2147483647 Bytes